# How the while statement is executed in C or how this array-referenced pointers work?

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

I started learning C and I had this exercise from the book "*Prentice Hall - The C Programming Language*".

**Chapter 5 Exercise 3:**
Write a pointer version of the fuction strcat that we showed in Chapter 2. strcat(s, t) copies the string t to the end of s.

I did the exercise but the first method that came up to my mind was:

```c
void stringcat(char *s, char *t){
    
    int i,j;
    i = j = 0;
    
    while(*(s+i) != '\0'){
        printf("%d", i);
        i++;
        
    }

    while ( (*(t+j)) != '\0'){
        *(s+i) = *(t+j);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

In main I had:

```c
int main(){
    char s[] = "Hola";
    char t[] = "lala";

    stringcat(s,t);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

At first sight I thought it was right but the actual output was `Holalalaa`.
Of course it was not the output that I expected, but then I coded this:

```c
void stringcat(char *s, char *t){
    
    int i,j;
    i = j = 0;
    
    while(*(s+i) != '\0'){
        printf("%d", i);
        i++;
        
    }
    
    while((*(s+i) = *(t+j)) != '\0'){
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

And the output was right.

But then I was thinking a lot about the first code because it's very similar to the second one but why the first output was wrong?. Is it something related with the while statement? or something with pointers?. I found it really hard to understand because you can't see what's happening in the array.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll get array overflow because `char s[] = "Hola";` has no room to concatenate. You'll find it easier to read by writing `*(s+i)` as `s[i]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I also thought about that but for that I have to return a new array right? Or is there any way to use void signature?.

Comment: Also, note that your first code snippet doesn't copy the terminating null character from the `t` string.

Comment: Allocate for another array which is the sum of the two lengths + 1 and return that from `char *stringcat(char *s, char *t)`

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks a lot I didn't notice that.

Comment: In `main` you can allocate sufficient space in `s` for the concatenated strings: `char s[16] = "Hola";`. However, doing that would have prevented you from spotting that your first code version doesn't work, as all elements of `s` after the "a" would be zero-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has more than the one problem that you found, but let's start with it.

Actually you are asking why

```c
    /* ... */
    while ((*(t+j)) != '\0') {
        *(s+i) = *(t+j);
        /* ... */
```

works differently than

```c
    /* ... */
    while ((*(s+i) = *(t+j)) != '\0') {
        /* ... */
```

I hope you see it already, now that both cases stand side by side, actually vertically ;-). In the first case the value of `t[j]` is compared *before* it is copied to `s[i]`. In the second case the comparison is done *after* the copy. That's why the second case copies the terminating `'\0'` to the target string, and the first case does not.

---

The output you get works accidentally, it is *Undefined Behavior*, since you are writing beyond the border of the target array. Fortunately for you, both strings are laying in sequence in the memory, and you are overwriting the source string with its own characters.

Because your first case does not copy the `'\0'`, the final `printf()` outputs more characters until a `'\0'` is encountered. By chance this is the last `'a'`.

---

As others commented, the target string has not enough space for the concatenated string. Provide some more space like this:

```c
    char s[10] = "Hola"; /* 10 is enough for both strings and the terminating '\0'. */
```

However, if you had done this already, the error would have not been revealed, because the last 6 characters of `s` are initialized with `'\0'`. Not copying the terminating `'\0'` makes no difference. You can see this if you use

```c
    char s[10] = "Hola\0xxxx";
```

---

I don't think that your solution is the expected one. Instead of `s[i]` you are using `*(s + i)`, which is essentially the same, accessing an array. Consider changing `s` (and in the course, `t`) in the function and use just `*s`.

---

*Side note: The `printf()` in the function is most probably a leftover from debugging. But I'm sure you know.*